# Confused on where exactly i should test my ie code. the tester is bugging me

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

ie6 has been bugging me up from a very long time from now. and i am feeling so frustrated. however here is the problem i am facing.

i have written the XHTML markup , html and css code. i want to test the cross browser compatibility, i know there are lots of tools out there to do it, and i am already using some of them.

i am on windows7, i have installed windows xp through vmware, and the HTML IDE i am using is, Microsoft Expression Web. for testing ie6 compatibility i have ie6 tester and Microsoft Expression web SuperPreview.

when i test my code using Windows XP and Microsoft Expression Web Super Preview the website renders perfectly fine. but when i use the tool ietester and browser.adobelab.com it displays with ugly alignment.

what is happening? windows xp comes with built in ie6 isn't it? i am using the tool from the very own creator of the crappy browser ie6 and it renders my page absolutely fine. then why is it that the tool browser.adobelab.com and ietester shows the different alignment and makes my page ugly. whom do i trust?

Comment: If you have an old copy of windows XP installing it and NOT updating it should leave you with a fresh copy of IE6 for testing.  I run a XP guest on VirtualBox for this exact purpose.

Comment: You should never trust "Live Views" from any software, always see the rendered result in the browser you're building for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[www.browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/)

This site will take screenshots for you and upload the pictures. That or if you're into spending money check out the [Multibrowser Viewer](http://www.multibrowserviewer.com), which featuers 16 or more standalone browsers to check your site in, as well as the [Litmusapp](http://litmusapp.com/), which is another login based website screenshotter, although I think there is an application for it too now..

:)

Comment: screenshots are fine, but don't cut it for testing dynamic elements of your site. You still need to actually run your site in each browser to see all the quirks.

Comment: @Spudley, that's why I linked to Multibrowser Viewer.

Comment: I wasn't criticising you; just making the point that browsershots on its own isn't sufficient.

Comment: I understand :), forgot to add the smiley I guess. But thanks for pointing it out to other readers :)

Answer (score 3):

The best "tool" to use at the moment is undoubtedly http://spoon.net/Browsers/

With a little plugin they let you run all kinds of browsers on your computer with no install.

When I found out about this, I dropped all the old methods.

Comment: This was what I was going to answer too!  Spoon is amazing, you can test anything! IE6-9, FF2-4, Chrome-6, Safari 3-5, Opera 9-10.  And it's quick, once  you load it the first time of the day, they all load pretty quickly after that (depending on your internet speed).

Comment: @nick "Note: Internet Explorer 9 is not supported on Windows XP."

Comment: That's because... Internet Explorer 9 is not supported on Windows XP, in general, that's not a spoon limit.

Comment: the plugin is simply brilliant, now my alignment has a new story to tell if i use this.

Answer (score 0):

I use browser labs alot and it seems to be extreamly accurate, if you compare it to an actual browser then it is pixel perfect. I would go with that but that is just my personal opinion.

Comment: i am a newbie and it is very painful to upload the files into server everytime you want to check the code. right now i don't want to edit my codes online. i want to test it locally. how can it show different screenshot for ie6.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar OS setup with windows 7 and XP running within a Virtual PC environment.  The setup I then implement is to point a host file record (C:\Windows\System 32\driver\etc\hosts) to my Windows 7 machine on the network.  This then allows me to view my development sites from this environment.

Within the XP environment I use Multiple IE's (http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) which then allows me to test in IE6 and IE7 side by side, whilst the Windows 7 environment allows me to test in IE8.

Comment: don't forget to add IE9 to your testing now that it's been released (so far just as beta, but full release won't be far off)

Comment: Agreed - though you can't run IE8 alongside IE9 as far as I'm aware so the best bet would be to have another VM running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that all XP version comes with IE6. Mine, for example, had IE7 after its installation. You should check that by clicking on the "?" and "about Internet Explorer".